# Big "alt attribute" in questions with several images in post

Tags: bug, tooltips

When I hover cursor in a question link with several images, the "popup" becomes too large:

[image: bug]

I noticed this issue in several sites from SE, a example, go to http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com and hover mouse in "Banners pra que te quero!" question.